# (node:3739) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error in start.js when running http://learnforge.autodesk.io tutorial

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying the http://learnforge.autodesk.io tutorial and am getting this warning/error when I try to run via debug:

```
(node:3739) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
warning.js:18
(node:3739) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
warning.js:18
(node:3739) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
warning.js:18
(node:3739) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
warning.js:18
(node:3739) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Here's the code from start.js the warning is referring to:

```
function writeOut(message) {
  if (console && typeof console.error === 'function')
    return console.error(message);
  process._rawDebug(message);
}
```

thanks!

Per Jose Mato's request, here is the full code from the warning.js file created by the debugger.

```
    (function (exports, require, module, process, internalBinding) {'use strict';

const config = process.binding('config');
const prefix = `(${process.release.name}:${process.pid}) `;
const { ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE } = require('internal/errors').codes;

exports.setup = setupProcessWarnings;

var cachedFd;
var acquiringFd = false;
function nop() {}

// Lazily loaded
var fs = null;

function writeOut(message) {
  if (console && typeof console.error === 'function')
    return console.error(message);
  process._rawDebug(message);
}

    function onClose(fd) {
  return () => {
    if (fs === null) fs = require('fs');
    try {
      fs.closeSync(fd);
    } catch {}
  };
}

function onOpen(cb) {
  return (err, fd) => {
    acquiringFd = false;
    if (fd !== undefined) {
      cachedFd = fd;
      process.on('exit', onClose(fd));
    }
    cb(err, fd);
    process.emit('_node_warning_fd_acquired', err, fd);
  };
}

function onAcquired(message) {
  // make a best effort attempt at writing the message
  // to the fd. Errors are ignored at this point.
  return (err, fd) => {
    if (err)
      return writeOut(message);
    if (fs === null) fs = require('fs');
    fs.appendFile(fd, `${message}\n`, nop);
  };
}

function acquireFd(cb) {
  if (cachedFd === undefined && !acquiringFd) {
    acquiringFd = true;
    if (fs === null) fs = require('fs');
    fs.open(config.warningFile, 'a', onOpen(cb));
  } else if (cachedFd !== undefined && !acquiringFd) {
    cb(null, cachedFd);
  } else {
    process.once('_node_warning_fd_acquired', cb);
  }
}

function output(message) {
  if (typeof config.warningFile === 'string') {
    acquireFd(onAcquired(message));
    return;
  }
  writeOut(message);
}

function doEmitWarning(warning) {
  return () => {
    process.emit('warning', warning);
  };
}

function setupProcessWarnings() {
  if (!process.noProcessWarnings && process.env.NODE_NO_WARNINGS !== '1') {
    process.on('warning', (warning) => {
      if (!(warning instanceof Error)) return;
      const isDeprecation = warning.name === 'DeprecationWarning';
      if (isDeprecation && process.noDeprecation) return;
      const trace = process.traceProcessWarnings ||
                    (isDeprecation && process.traceDeprecation);
      var msg = prefix;
      if (warning.code)
        msg += `[${warning.code}] `;
      if (trace && warning.stack) {
        msg += `${warning.stack}`;
      } else {
        const toString =
          typeof warning.toString === 'function' ?
            warning.toString : Error.prototype.toString;
        msg += `${toString.apply(warning)}`;
      }
      if (typeof warning.detail === 'string') {
        msg += `\n${warning.detail}`;
      }
      output(msg);
    });
  }

  // process.emitWarning(error)
  // process.emitWarning(str[, type[, code]][, ctor])
  // process.emitWarning(str[, options])
  process.emitWarning = (warning, type, code, ctor, now) => {
    var detail;
    if (type !== null && typeof type === 'object' && !Array.isArray(type)) {
      ctor = type.ctor;
      code = type.code;
      if (typeof type.detail === 'string')
        detail = type.detail;
      type = type.type || 'Warning';
    } else if (typeof type === 'function') {
      ctor = type;
      code = undefined;
      type = 'Warning';
    }
    if (typeof code === 'function') {
      ctor = code;
      code = undefined;
    }
    if (code !== undefined && typeof code !== 'string')
      throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('code', 'string', code);
    if (type !== undefined && typeof type !== 'string')
      throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('type', 'string', type);
    if (warning === undefined || typeof warning === 'string') {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
      warning = new Error(warning);
      warning.name = String(type || 'Warning');
      if (code !== undefined) warning.code = code;
      if (detail !== undefined) warning.detail = detail;
      Error.captureStackTrace(warning, ctor || process.emitWarning);
    }
    if (!(warning instanceof Error)) {
      throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('warning', ['Error', 'string'], warning);
    }
    if (warning.name === 'DeprecationWarning') {
      if (process.noDeprecation)
        return;
      if (process.throwDeprecation)
        throw warning;
    }
    if (now) process.emit('warning', warning);
    else process.nextTick(doEmitWarning(warning));
  };
}

});
```

Comment: Hi, the error it seems is not coming from this file. Do you have the entire code? This error appears when you call a function which returns a promise and you don't perform the .catch in case there is an exception. That's the meaning of “Unhandled Promise Rejection” … a promise is being rejected but there is no a proper .catch associated

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Jose.  I just posted the full code, this comes from a file created by the debugger titled warning.js.  I'm very new to this so please let me know if I need to post code from the tutorial.  Thanks!

Comment: Like Jose has pointed out the `error` you've post was not thrown by line 18 in `warning.js` - instead that line only wrote the error message to console. You can step through the code and narrow the real error down in the tutorial code.

Comment: Hi Bryan :)) I was meaning the code of your application or at least, try this first, put this code to catch unhandled rejections, perform the console.log and more info will appear where the exact problem is: https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-prevent-your-node-js-process-from-crashing-5d40247b8ab2